# jTable Plugin with ASP .NET CORE 2.0

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, jtable

I am trying to run jTable plugin for rendering my GRID to perform CRUD operations in a .NET Core-2.0 project. After multiple debugging attempts, I am unable to render my data on my VIEW with the plugin.

I even did the same in a ASP .NET-MVC project and the plugin worked correctly.

Is there any configuration changes or additions that I need to do in order for this plugin to work correctly?

Plugin link: http://www.jtable.org

VIEW:

```
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "User Login Page";
Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure- 
requests">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- STYLES -->
<link href="~/lib//jtable.2.4.0/themes/metro/blue/jtable.css" 
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/lib//jtable.2.4.0/themes/metro/blue/jquery-ui.css" 
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!-- SCRIPTS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery- 
1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery- 
ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"     
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.6.2/modernizr.js"> 
 </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jtable.2.4.0/jquery.jtable.js"</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="StudentTableContainer"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        alert("Reached");
        $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable({
            title: 'The Student List',
            actions: {
                listAction: '/MyLocalDashboard/GetItems'
            },
            fields: {
                StudentID: {
                    key: true,
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    list: true,
                    title: 'Student ID',
                },
                StudentName: {
                    title: 'Student Name',
                    width: '23%'
                }
            }
        });

        //Load student list from server
        $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable('load');
    });

</script>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
 return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetItems()
{
 string actionName=this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
  try
  {              
    //Example Add
    List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>() {
      new Student(){ StudentID=1, StudentName="Bill"},
      new Student(){ StudentID=2, StudentName="Steve"},
      new Student(){ StudentID=3, StudentName="Ram"},
      new Student(){ StudentID=1, StudentName="Moin"}
      };

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(studentList);
    return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = json, TotalRecordCount = studentList.Count });
   }
  catch (Exception ex)
   {
    ViewBag.getActionName = actionName;
    return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
   }
 }

 private class Student
 {
   public int StudentID { get; set; }
   public string StudentName { get; set; }
 }
```

It would be really great if someone could direct me in the correct direction to setup this plugin with .NET Core-2.0.

**UPDATE**:

I was not able to find anything for this issue in .NET Core. If someone has setup this plugin and could provide with a direction to go, it would be of great help.

Thanks Again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after setting up this plugin in a .NET CORE and .NET MVC Framework project [here](https://github.com/rahsharm77) and getting valuable input by this [user](https://github.com/maliming) based on [this](https://github.com/volosoft/jtable/issues/2198) discussion, the resolution to this problem in .NET CORE is by adding this line in your `Startup.cs` under `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1).AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
```

Reason why this plugin was not working with .NET CORE:

> Because the naming style used by JTable is not the same as for ASP.NET CORE which basically means that the JSON returned by the plugin needs to be handled in .NET CORE explicitly.

After adding our DefaultContractResolver(), the following JSON is returned which is required by the plugin:

```
{
    "Result": "OK"
}
```

Original JSON being returned by .NET CORE to the plugin:

```
{
    "result": "OK"
}
```

After adding/modifying this option, the JTable grid is being rendered correctly now in my .NET CORE project.

I hope this helps someone else who is facing a similar problem in setting up this plugin in .NET CORE

Cheers